# C# delete query not working

Tags: c#, sql

I have written this query in c# , query syntax is OK, query is also receiving parameter values as I have checked using breakpoints and also same query is working in SQL server management studio, but in visual studio it does not gives any error but also does not delete item from table.

```
private void deleteItem(int itemId, int saleId)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);

    SqlCommand deleteItem = new SqlCommand(
      "Delete FROM items_in_sales WHERE sale_id=@sale_id AND item_id=@item_id", 
       conn);

    deleteItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sale_id", itemId);
    deleteItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_id", saleId);

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        deleteItem.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

please help.

Comment: check values of `itemId` and `saleId`, does in db exists record with that `sale_id` and `item_id` ?

Comment: The ExecuteNonQuery method returns an integer that tells you how many rows have been deleted by your query. Get that return and display it somewhere or use the debugger to see the result. Tell us what value you get.

Comment: I also suggest using a `using` block. But that seems unrelated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix your parameters they are wrong way around

```
deleteItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sale_id", itemId);
deleteItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_id", saleId);
```

should be

```
deleteItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sale_id", saleId);
deleteItem.Parameters.AddWithValue("@item_id", itemId);
```